# Cannot Open 16 kbps Wav file

Tags: asp.net, html5-audio

I am in a very strange situation regarding wav audio file.

Currently trying to open a wav file named "call1.wav" which is 16 kbps bit rate. When i open the call1.wav file in browser it does't work. Then I tried to open the file manually using windows media player and vlc, found there also file not opening.

Windows wav audio file are opening correctly(160 kbps). Ultimately i want my browser should play this file.

Now my question is what other ways i can try before i give up or should i confirm my client that call1.wav file is corrupt.

I Tried:
1. opening through 3-4 players
2. Converting the file into mp3 format but unable to open file.

My web application is asp.net c# based.

Comment: If you've tried a couple of programs that claim to support WAV files and they don't work, you can draw either conclusion: 1) you are dealing with a really obscure variant of WAV file or 2) the file is corrupted. Either way, sounds like you just need to obtain a different file.

Comment: @mason thanks for marking attention.. i too think now there is some issue with file only..